# HttpCookie.HttpOnly in .NET and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookies, httponly

Hello
A web site was developed and deployed to client. In some cases, I need to set the flag `HttpCookie.HttpOnly = true`. Okay - I have done it. Next question:

1. Is Cookie available after setting flag in JavaScript?
2. or maybe some restriction when I am using JavaScript?
3. or do I need to make some changes in existing JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of using [`HttpOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.httponly.aspx) is to prevent Javascript from accessing the cookie, primarily to prevent XSS attacks.  There are decent write-ups on [CodingHorror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533046.aspx) about it.

Bottom line: if you need access to the cookie with Javascript you can not use HttpOnly.

Comment: From the MSDN description linked above: "...specifies whether a cookie is accessible by client-side script... true if the cookie has the HttpOnly attribute and cannot be accessed through a client-side script..."